# Cursor position 'o' and 'O' insert command with count number

Tags: cursor-movement, insert-mode

The default behaviour of the `o` and `O` when prepended with a count is to keep the cursor always at the bottom.

I'm wondering if there's a native way to get the cursor at the top.

The way I'm doing this for this example is:

```
5O<Esc>4ki
```

## Example:

### Starting from this:

```
line 1 qux [here is the cursor in `normal` mode]
line 2 foo
line 3 bar
```

### Get to this (added 5 lines above):

```
line 1 [here is the cursor in `insert` mode]
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5 
line 6 qux
line 7 foo
line 8 bar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting is not fun, so an immediate improvement would be to use `:help '[` instead of `4k`. I am not sure if you can do better without some kind of mapping:

```
:nnoremap gO O<Esc>'[i
```

where `gO` does the full dance for you.

--- Rest of the original answer ---

```
:nnoremap <expr> gO '<Cmd>normal ' .. v:count1 .. 'O<CR>`[i'
```

- `:help <expr>` makes Vim evaluate the RHS of the mapping at runtime.
- `:help <Cmd>` is the new `:help c_ctrl-u`.
- `:help v:count1` is the count we gave to our mapping, how many empty lines we want to add.
- `` normal 5O<CR>`[i `` is the actual command executed for a count of 5.
- `5O<CR>` opens 5 lines above the current line, leaving the cursor on the last line inserted.
- `` `[ `` moves the cursor to the first line of the last change, therefore on the first inserted line.
- `i`, well… enters insert mode.

I can think of at least three other sequences of intermediate steps to obtain the same result but it always ends with a custom mapping so, there.

Comment: Why the need for `<Cmd>normal` (without bang?)? Wouldn't `nnoremap <expr> gO v:count1 .. 'O<esc>''[i'` work too? (Change quoted apostrophe to backtick for marks as desired; getting nested backticks in a comment is hard.)

Comment: It wouldn't, but ``:nnoremap gO O<Esc>`[i`` would, actually, which is much simpler than my over-engineered solution.

Comment: Huh, not sure _why_ it wouldn't work, but glad it simplified :)